# How to configure a FreeBSD port with default values (recursively)?

Tags: automation, freebsd, compile, configure

After doing a research in multiple search engines and reading https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/building.html and https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/makefile-options.html I don't seem to find any explanations or references on how to skip the `ncurses` dialogs which pop up when running `make install` in a port with (a lot of) dependencies, e.g. `/usr/ports/x11/gnome3` in 10.1, in favour of using the default values which are preselected in the dialog.

`make config-recursive` allows to configure everything and holding down <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a workaround, but far from elegant (i.e. I'm searching for a solution based on a command). `yes "" | make install` doesn't do anything as well as

```
exec 3<&0
yes "" | sudo make config-recursive
```

inpired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999114/linux-pipe-into-python-ncurses-script-stdin-and-termios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [How can I avoid the prompts when installing a FreeBSD port?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/how-can-i-avoid-the-prompts-when-installing-a-freebsd-port)

It's still pretty much the same, although I'd recommend setting BATCH in `/etc/make.conf` rather than your shell profile.